# Change border color of input field

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I use a CSS framework (Bulma). However, I would like to design my input field a little differently. For example, it should have a red border.
I use `scss`. However, it does not work. When I import my class, the border is not displayed in red.

How can I adapt my input field in addition to the CSS framework, e.g. so that I have a red border?

```
import React from 'react'
import './style/General.scss'


function General() {



    return (
        <div>
                        <div className="field">
                            <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                                <input className="input section-changing-input" type="text" value="Hello" />
                                <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                                    <i className="fas fa-futbol"></i>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default General
```

General.scss

```
section-changing-input {
    input {
        border-color: crimson !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong, it attempts to target an `input` inside `section-changing-input`. so there are two things wrong with it: the missing dot infront of the classname and the non-existent nesting. And I noticed you posted the same (or nearly the same) question twice. Not cool.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the Bulma CSS library before your custom CSS. Otherwise, the custom CSS changes you make will not be applied.

Comment: Sure, I have already done that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Bulma's input borders are set with the `$input-border-color` variable.  If you're compiling Bulma in with your own scss files, then simply declare that as red *before* importing Bulma.

Comment: With this variable I would change the colour for all input fields. However, I would like to change this colour only for two input fields and not for all as mentioned.